# Which audio smoothing algorithm has the lowest latency?

Tags: audio, lowpass-filter, audio-processing, smoothing

I am working on an audio smoothing project. My inputs are from a record scratching MIDI controller, and I am trying to produce a smooth output (the raw data creates noisy audio).

I'm using a simple rectangular boxcar algorithm, which works fine, but introduces latency - there's a pause at the beginning of the audio output, which I want to minimise.

I tried using a triangular/weighted algorithm, in the hopes of improving the smoothing enough that I could reduce the width of the filter (more width = more latency). But it didn't seem to improve things.

I've also tried looking into more complex algorithms, such as Savitzky-Golay, but they seem to be optimised for retaining signal shape rather than reducing latency.

I'm struggling to find smoothing algorithms that are optimal for minimising latency. All my attempts to research lead me instead to algorithms that are optimal for retaining signal shape. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the algorithms you are using? Have tried "simple" lowpass solutions like running averaging and leaky integration?

Comment: Exponential smoothing if you can live with nonlinear phase is simple and low latency.

Comment: I think we need a lot more detail about your specific setup and what exactly is your problem. Is your input a wave file, a stream of MIDI events or something else ? What "noise" is your input producing and what is acceptable and what isn't' ? What exactly are you trying to "smooth" and by how much?  You can't "smooth" and audio wave form  directly without doing serious damage. You may be able to smooth an envelope or some MIDI events. Sorry, it's probably obvious to you, but we can't mind read